# Kendo DropdownList showing [Object Object] when trying to populate

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to populate my Kendo Dropdownlist with enum values. But it is showing [Object Object] as result.

HTML:

```
<kendo-dropdownlist id="ddlRoleType"
formControlName="roleType"
[(ngModel)]="roleType"
style="width:100%"
[data]="roleTypes"
[textField]="name"
[valueField]="value"></kendo-dropdownlist>
```

In Component.ts:

```
roleTypes: roleType[];
this.roleTypes = EnumExtension.getNamesAndValues(EnumRoleType);
```

The roleType Class:

```
export class roleType {
    name: string;
    value: number;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `''` around **`name`** and **`value`** like shown below.

```
[textField]="'name'"
[valueField]="'value'"
```

Refer this [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nd9cpn-y6xas8?file=app/app.component.ts) for working example.

Comment: that or use `textfield="name"`; easier IMO